# devpi replacing & with &amp; while accessing mirror link to download from s3

Tags: python, html, amazon-s3, pypi, devpi

I am trying to use [dockerized devpi](https://github.com/muccg/docker-devpi) to mirror my organization's private pypi(pypicloud) hosted using a s3 bucket.
The simple index is visible but when I try to install one of the packages listed, I get a 403 from S3. Initially I thought it to be a permissions issue, but on comparing the download URL from direct pip install from private pypi (which works fine) and the URL from devpi(local mirror) pip install, I see that all the `&` between the parameters like Signature, Expires and AWSAccessKeyId have been replaced by `&amp;`

On manually replacing these `&amp;` back with `&`, the URL works perfectly and I can download the package. My question is, how to fix the issue within devpi or any other alternatives to be explored for mirroring a remote pypi repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved by updating the devpi versions to the latest as suggested by the devpi team here:
https://github.com/devpi/devpi/issues/762